# image is not a member of system.windows.forms.control

Tags: vb.net

i have 10 imagebox named imagebox1,imagebox2.....imagebox10

when i click a button , it runs a sub called "load" which  loads the images from imagelist into imageboxes in a loop

```
Private Sub LOAD(ByVal task As String)
Dim j As Integer , ctl1 As Control
For j = 1 To 10
ctl1 = Controls(" PictureBox" & Format(j))   
ctl1.Image = imglistPics.Images(j) 'THİS LİNE GİVES THE ERROR(image is not a member of system.windows.forms.control)
ctl.visible = true   'THİS LİNE WORKS
next   
End Sub
```

i've tried this one instead. But it gives this error "System.NullReferenceException". But imagelist is not null!

```
CType(ctl1, PictureBox).Image = imglistPics.Images(j)
```

Comment: you probably are running out of images. the image indices in the image list will run from 0 to 9 not 1 to 10.  The image referenced by `.Images(10)` will be Nothing in that case.

Comment: you have a space in `" PictureBox"` it should be `"PictureBox"` and what is `ctl` is it a typo? `ctl1` should be declared as `PictureBox`.

Comment: there is no space before picturebox in code.. i write here wrong.And there is 100's of images in imagelist
How can i declare the ctl as picturebox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do like this

```
    Dim j As Integer, ctl1 As PictureBox
    For j = 1 To 10
        ctl1 = CType(Controls("PictureBox" & Format(j)), PictureBox)
        ctl1.Image = imglistPics.Images(j - 1) 'Note: image index starts from 0
        ctl1.Visible = True 
    Next
```